# expected value and variance of a fair die rolled 10 times.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, solution-verification

My exercise is to calculate both the expected value and the variance of a fair die being rolled 10 times:

I want to verify my solution / get a hint as to what i'm doing wrong:

For the expected value i got:

$$10 * (1 * \frac{1}{6} + 2 * \frac{1}{6} + 3 * \frac{1}{6} + 4 * \frac{1}{6} + 5 * \frac{1}{6} + 6 * \frac{1}{6}) / 6 = 21/6 = 10* 3.5 = 35$$

And for the Variance i got:

$$\sum^{60}_{i\geq10}(x_i-\mu)^2 * p_i = \sum^{60}_{i\geq10}(i-35)^2 * \frac{1}{6}^{10} = 0.000182746$$

My Variance seems kind of wrong, but i'm not sure as to why.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of rolling $11$ when rolling 10 times means rolling $9$ ones and $1$ two, which could be done in
$$
\binom{10}{1} (1/6)^{10}
$$
ways, and you counted only $1/6^{10}$ inyour variance calculation.

---

A different way to look at $S_{10} = \sum_{k=1}^{10} X_k$ is to notice since $X_k$ are iid, the expected value and variance of $S_{10}$ and of $10X_k$ are the same. In other words,
$$
\mathbb{E}[S_n] = \mathbb{E}[nX_1] = n\mathbb{E}[X_1] = 3.5n,
$$
which for $n-10$ yields $\mathbb{E}[S_{10}] = 35$.

Similarly,
$$
\mathbb{Var}S_n = \mathbb{Var}(nX_1) = n^2 \mathbb{Var}X_1,
$$
and that variance on the RHS is much easier to compute than the direct calculation you are attempting...

Comment: oh, so the variance of one die being rolled multiplied by 100 is my variance in that case?

Comment: @AnotherNoone yes :)